# using apache camel's camel-kafka component to commit consumer offsets manually

Tags: java, apache-camel, apache-kafka

I was able to play with apache kafka commit offset classes and able to commit using **ConsumerConnector**. I looked in to apache camel-kafka component having consumer option as "**autoCommitEnable**" same as "**auto.commit.enable**" property.
Now is there any property or method in Camel Java DSL where after consuming a message we can commit offsets manually (through provided methods or consumer options in URL)
**OR** 
we have to again use Kafka Consumer API's to commit consumer offsets?

Answer (score 0):

You can commit using KafkaManualCommit

Please check the documentation 
https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-kafka/src/main/docs/kafka-component.adoc#using-manual-commit-with-kafka-consumer

```
public void process(Exchange exchange) {
    KafkaManualCommit manual =
        exchange.getIn().getHeader(KafkaConstants.MANUAL_COMMIT, KafkaManualCommit.class);
    manual.commitSync();
}
```